# How to filtr json output python

Tags: python, json, zabbix

I'm new to python (just learning) and I want to extract the hostname + specify element with the last value from the zabbix database, but I'm having trouble filtering the output, I don't know how to display just one specific element. So far I have the hostname and all the elements the host contains, but I want to display one specific element, for example, system.uptime, but I don't know how to extract this one element.

Second question: how can I get a nicer output? So far I have system.uptime in seconds, is it possible to somehow convert this to values - days/hours/min?
Also, can I get the output in columns? To make the output look nicer, as below

Hostname
item.name(system.uptime): item.value

Thanks for your help

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json

ZABBIX_API_URL = "http://localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php"
UNAME = "Admin"
PWORD = "zabbix"

r = requests.post(ZABBIX_API_URL,
                  json={
                      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                      "method": "user.login",
                      "params": {
                          "user": UNAME,
                          "password": PWORD},
                      "id": 1
                  })


AUTHTOKEN = r.json()["result"]

r = requests.post(ZABBIX_API_URL,
                  json={
                            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                            "method": "host.get",
                            "params": {
                                "output": [
                                    "name"
                                ],
                                "selectItems": [
                                    "name",
                                    "lastvalue",
                                    "key_"
                                ]
                                },
                            "id": 2,
                            "auth": AUTHTOKEN
                        })

print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
#Logout user
print("\nLogout user")
r = requests.post(ZABBIX_API_URL,
                  json={
                      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                      "method": "user.logout",
                      "params": {},

                      "id": 2,
                      "auth": AUTHTOKEN
                  })
```

my output

```
{
                    "key_": "system.uptime",
                    "lastvalue": "7635",
                    "name": "System uptime"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "system.users.num",
                    "lastvalue": "1",
                    "name": "Number of logged in users"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.queue_size[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0.002132505683045899",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk average queue size (avgqu-sz)"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.read.await[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk read request avg waiting time (r_await)"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.read.rate[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk read rate"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.read.time.rate[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk read time (rate)"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.util[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0.6532914235362834",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk utilization"
                },
                {
                    "key_": "vfs.dev.write.await[nvme0n1]",
                    "lastvalue": "0.1358211148456916",
                    "name": "nvme0n1: Disk write request avg waiting time (w_await)"
                },
```

Comment: 1) `next(d for d in r.json() if d["key_"] == "system.uptime")` 2) `"{:0>8}".format(str(timedelta(seconds=7635)))`

Comment: so to clarify, you want a mapping like `{_key: {lastvalue:..., name:...}}` for each row?

Comment: I want to get this output, but only for system.uptime

hostname: xxxxx \n
"name": "System uptime" \n
"lastvalue": "7635" \n